# how to fix triple drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following code and Numbers inside the values :

I want all of the codes below:

```
<option value="1" class="sub_1">
```

Change to :

```
<option value="" id="1" class="sub_1">
```

Actually I want the values ​​to be empty and numbers inside the values placed the other ID in option like id="" or data-id="" or ....

```js
    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

  function cascadeSelect(parent, child) {
    var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
    child.data('options', childOptions);
    parent.change(function() {
      childOptions.remove();
      child
        .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
        .change();
    })

    childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

  }

  $(function() {
    cascadeForm = $('.cascadeTest');
    orgSelect = cascadeForm.find('.orgSelect');
    terrSelect = cascadeForm.find('.terrSelect');
    locSelect = cascadeForm.find('.locSelect');

    cascadeSelect(orgSelect, terrSelect);
    cascadeSelect(terrSelect, locSelect);
  });
```

```html
<form action="#" class="cascadeTest">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="orgSelect" class="orgSelect">
          <option value="0">Select an Organization</option>
          <option value="1">Organization 1</option>
          <option value="2">Organization 2</option>
          <option value="3">Organization 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Territory:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="terrSelect" class="terrSelect">
          <option value="0" class="static">- All Territories -</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_2">Organization 2 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="4" class="sub_2">Organization 2 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="5" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="6" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="7" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="locSelect" class="locSelect">
          <option value="0" class="static">- All Locations -</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_2">Organization 1 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_2">Organization 1 - Territory 2 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_3">Organization 2 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_3">Organization 2 - Territory 1 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="4" class="sub_4">Organization 2 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="5" class="sub_5">Organization 3 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="6" class="sub_6">Organization 3 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="7" class="sub_7">Organization 3 - Territory 3 - Location 1</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Editing my whole answer as the problem has been altered.
As you only want to give the user the choice to select options based on another selects current value.

Firstly, I have put the `terrSelect` and `locSelect` to `disabled` as default. Thus the user must first select an `orgSelect`. When `orgSelect` changes, we will enable `terrSelect`. Then, we loop through all of `terrSelect` child elements, and disable those not matching the value of `locSelect`. The same procedure is then repeated for `locSelect`:

```
<form action="#" class="cascadeTest">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="orgSelect" class="orgSelect">
          <option value="0">Select an Organization</option>
          <option value="1">Organization 1</option>
          <option value="2">Organization 2</option>
          <option value="3">Organization 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Territory:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="terrSelect" class="terrSelect" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="0" class="static">- All Territories -</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_2">Organization 2 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="4" class="sub_2">Organization 2 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="5" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 1</option>
          <option value="6" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 2</option>
          <option value="7" class="sub_3">Organization 3 - Territory 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location:</th>
      <td>
        <select name="locSelect" class="locSelect" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="0" class="static">- All Locations -</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="1" class="sub_1">Organization 1 - Territory 1 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_2">Organization 1 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="2" class="sub_2">Organization 1 - Territory 2 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_3">Organization 2 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="3" class="sub_3">Organization 2 - Territory 1 - Location 2</option>
          <option value="4" class="sub_4">Organization 2 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="5" class="sub_5">Organization 3 - Territory 1 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="6" class="sub_6">Organization 3 - Territory 2 - Location 1</option>
          <option value="7" class="sub_7">Organization 3 - Territory 3 - Location 1</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script>
    $('.orgSelect').change(function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
        $('.terrSelect').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.terrSelect').children('option').each(function(){
            if( !$(this).hasClass( 'sub_'+selected ) ){
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }               
        });
    });
    $('.terrSelect').change(function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
        $('.locSelect').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.locSelect').children('option').each(function(){
            if( !$(this).hasClass( 'sub_'+selected ) ){
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('value','');` should be `$(this).val('');`

Comment: `attr('id', $(this).attr('value'))` should be `attr('id', $(this).val())`

Comment: Sorry but I am Beginner in jQuery is possible for you to fix it for me in the jsfiddle?
thank you very much

Comment: Thank you, but it's not like my code does not work anymore, we have chosen the first option the second option is enabled, and when the second was chosen to enable a third

Comment: I want when the values be empty placed the other content into values for post to other page

Comment: Okay, then its a completely differen issue. See my updated answer. This should atleast guide you in the correct direction

Comment: But the values ​​are filled with numbers and I cannot put other content on that

Comment: This is thing that you friends said I cannot fill the values with other content

see my friends I want all of the codes like below:                    `<option value="1" class="sub_3">hello</option>`              Change to :                                                 `<option value="hello" id="1" class="sub_1">hello</option>`      the values be fill  with other content like hello and the numbers inside values fill in other id and without problem for script

Comment: There is no one to help me؟!

Comment: @MelanieUK: use .prop() instead of .attr()

Amirali, When someone gives an answer (and revises it to accomodate you), you should probably wait more than an hour before spamming your own thread with "There is no one to help me."  Sounds whiny, demanding and entitled.

Answer (score 1):

This is thing that you friends said I cannot fill the values with other content

see my friends 
I want all of the codes like below:

```
<option value="1" class="sub_3">hello</option>
```

Change to :

```
 <option value="hello" id="1" class="sub_1">hello</option>
```

the values be fill  with other content like hello and the numbers inside values fill in other id and without problem for script

Comment: This isnt a place to have someone write the entire code for you. My answer above should give you some idea about how to solve it. Nevertheless have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsp7qeev/4/ it shows that you can set whatever value to the options you like.

Comment: thank you very much for to help , Sorry but I am Beginner in jQuery  , one other question : in your script how i can the options are disabled isn't displayed?

Comment: Its not possible to set any "hidden"-state to a option-element in html. Because of this, you will have to store the sub1, sub2, sub3 and so on elements in their own strings. And then remove the content of the dropdown on change, and insert the string containing the elements that are going to be enabled

Comment: it's work just with css :) ----     select option[disabled="disabled"]{
 display:none;
}